# Print /proc/slabinfo by creating a kernel routine

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

+
 trying to learn/tinker with the Linux kernel by following some PDFs and online resources. 
I wanted to print cache allocations using kmalloc_caches[], print somewhat similar info present by `cat`ing /proc/slabinfo

So far, I have come to understand I have implement `s_show` (on line 5421 in `/mm/slub.c`) on kernel version 3.3
I understand most of the function and any function calls made inside it. But what puzzles me are the arguments passed to it. Cause, when I search where `s_show()` is called, this is what I find:

```
 static const struct seq_operations slabinfo_op = {
     .start = s_start,
     .next = s_next,
     .stop = s_stop,
     .show = s_show,
 };
```

Now, I understand somewhat of what is going on here, but I still don't get where the arguments are coming from.

s_show() function :

```
static int s_show(struct seq_file *m, void *p)
{
    unsigned long nr_partials = 0;
    unsigned long nr_slabs = 0;
    unsigned long nr_inuse = 0;
    unsigned long nr_objs = 0;
    unsigned long nr_free = 0;
    struct kmem_cache *s;
    int node;

    s = list_entry(p, struct kmem_cache, list);

    for_each_online_node(node) {
        struct kmem_cache_node *n = get_node(s, node);

        if (!n)
            continue;

        nr_partials += n->nr_partial;
        nr_slabs += atomic_long_read(&n->nr_slabs);
        nr_objs += atomic_long_read(&n->total_objects);
        nr_free += count_partial(n, count_free);
    }

    nr_inuse = nr_objs - nr_free;

    seq_printf(m, "%-17s %6lu %6lu %6u %4u %4d", s->name, nr_inuse,
           nr_objs, s->size, oo_objects(s->oo),
           (1 << oo_order(s->oo)));
    seq_printf(m, " : tunables %4u %4u %4u", 0, 0, 0);
    seq_printf(m, " : slabdata %6lu %6lu %6lu", nr_slabs, nr_slabs,
           0UL);
    seq_putc(m, '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the code of `s_start`, `s_next` and `s_stop` functions -- perhaps they offer you some help.

Comment: I looked at that, this is s_start `static void *s_start(struct seq_file *m, loff_t *pos)`,  s_next :  `static void *s_next(struct seq_file *m, void *p, loff_t *pos)` s_stop : `static void s_stop(struct seq_file *m, void *p)`. This is what I get. Still don't understand about the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The `seq_file` argument is really the file into which you're outputting the data you want to print. It is automatically constructed.

However, the interesting thing is the `p` argument. To understand where it comes from, see this code:

```
static void *s_start(struct seq_file *m, loff_t *pos)
{
        loff_t n = *pos;

        mutex_lock(&cache_chain_mutex);
        if (!n)
                print_slabinfo_header(m);

        return seq_list_start(&cache_chain, *pos);
}

static void *s_next(struct seq_file *m, void *p, loff_t *pos)
{
        return seq_list_next(p, &cache_chain, pos);
}

static void s_stop(struct seq_file *m, void *p)
{
        mutex_unlock(&cache_chain_mutex);
}
```

The `s_start` and `s_next` functions return what is given as the `p` argument. You may want to read the code of `seq_list_start` and `seq_list_next`.

Comment: From what I undertand after looking at them, they [seq_list_start] gives you the head of the list (returns a [list_head]) and [seq_list_next] returns the next in the list. [seq_list_next] also has a argument [void *p] like s_show has *p